How to reinterpret a value as bytes in a compile-time context in C++
I'm trying to implement a hash function that can be used at compile-time. To achieve this, I need to reinterpret a value (e.g., an int or a float) as its raw bytes.
However, when using compile-time evaluation, pointer type punning (reinterpretation) is not allowed due to strict aliasing and other restrictions.
Here's a simplified example to illustrate the issue:
template <typename T>
constexpr size_t hash(const T& value) {
    const unsigned char* byte_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&value); // NOT allowed.

    size_t hash = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
        hash ^= byte_ptr[i];
    }
    return hash;
}

Is there a standard-compliant way to reinterpret a value as bytes in a constexpr context?

Which version of the Standard are you using? C++20/23/26?

std::bit_cast?

std::bit_cast (available since C++20) supports constexpr.
You can bit_cast to std::array and then use std::array::operator[] (which supports constexpr as well) to access the bytes:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <bit>

template <typename T>
constexpr size_t byte_sum(const T& value) {
    //const unsigned char* byte_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&value); // NOT allowed.
    auto arr = std::bit_cast<std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(value)>>(value);
    size_t hash = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i) {
        hash ^= arr[i];
    }
    return hash;
}

int main() {
    constexpr double d = 5;
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr size_t h = byte_sum(d);
}

Live demo

why use data() instead of [] ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you are right, it's simpler - updated.

How can you tell when it's a valid cast?

@DavidG what do you mean ?

@wohlstad I've never seen a conversion between double and std::array. Would it work if you had given bit_cast any type, or are there only specific types that work with that cast?

@DavidG see the std::bit_cast documentation. I don't feel confident to say that it is possible for any type, but for sure it will work well for casting primitive types (like the OP mentioned) to byte arrays. See also the live demo in my answer.

... In general it should work for casting between trivially copyable types.
